# How does the Kedei 3.5" 800*480 SPI touch screen version 1.1 work with a Pi 4?

Tags: pi-4, touchscreen, spi

I am trying to set up a Kedei Raspberry Pi Display version 1.1 2017/10/10 Type 3590 (horizontal 800*480px) with my Pi 4. Unfortunately, I didn't manage to get the Touch Screen running on SPI. The HDMI input works so far!

For now, I followed this [tutorial](https://www.zeroboy.eu/kedei-hdmi-tft-480-x-800/) (Sorry, its German, but its more or less a translation of the [eBay seller's tutorial](https://www.ebay.de/itm/New-3-5-inch-480x800-IPS-LCD-Touch-Screen-Display-USB-HDMI-For-Raspberry-Pi/392805006356?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)). I also tried to download the "official" [Kedei Driver](http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html) (LCD_show_35hdmi_Horizontal).

Until now, my screen wasn't working, it just shows a blue/black screen.

Do you have any ideas what I might do wrong? On the Kedei page, it doesn't list the Pi 4, might this be a problem?

My `/boot/config`:

```
#hdmi_safe=1
#disable_overscan=1
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720
#config_hdmi_boost=4
#sdtv_mode=2
#arm_freq=800
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi
dtparam=audio=on
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0 
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=0,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=10000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=199,xmax=3999,ymin=199,ymax=3999
```

Comment: I've edited in the information you had put in a comment. In future if you have more information to add to a question you can use the edit button at the bottom of your question. Since you're new here I recommend you take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dtoverlay` value looks wrong in your `/boot/config.txt` file.

Follow this guide: http://www.epyon.be/2019/01/12/raspberry-pi-3-b-with-kedei-3-5-inch-480x320-tf-lcd-display/#comment-161327

**PS:** You will have to do this every time you do a kernel version upgrade so that the kernel links are re-established.